# searching in children model using ANY is so slow in EF

Tags: entity-framework, linq

```
public class Student
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int TeacherId { get; set; }

public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

public class Nim
{
public int Id{ get; set; }
public int NIM { get; set; }
public bool Valid { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public int NimId { get; set; } //this is fk
public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

i want to get list of NIM on Teacher by finding with name of teacher here is my first code,
i can do that using this code and the performance is good and fast

```
string keyword = "John";
using (TestingEntities1 db = new TestingEntities1())
{
var models = db.Teachers.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(keyword)).
GroupBy(x => x.NimId).Select(i => new { i.FirstOrDefault().NimId });
}
```

then i add feature to also enable get the list of NIM from child name which is Student,
I have tried using "Any" keyword, but the performance is very slow load the result (i have many data in my database)

below is my code, i used "Any"

```
string keyword = "John";
using (TestingEntities1 db = new TestingEntities1())
{
var models = db.Teachers.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(keyword) || a.Students.Any(x=>x.Name.Equals(keyword))).
GroupBy(x => x.NimId).Select(i => new { i.FirstOrDefault().NimId });

}
```

Can you give me a proper way to do that and also good sped load result with my case ?

Comment: which db? if its a relational db, have we setup the right indexes (nonclustered index on Student.Name)?

Comment: What's the point of `GroupBy(x => x.NimId).Select(i => new { i.FirstOrDefault().NimId });`? Why not a simple. `Distinct(teacher=>teacher.NimId)` ?

Comment: First of all, the `Name` column in both tables should be indexed. After that, you'll have to use eg SQL Server Profiler to log the generated query to see what's going on. The query should look like `SELECT DISTINCT NimID from Teacher t left join Student s on t.Id=s.TeacherID where t.Name = @p0 or s.Name=@p0`. The `GroupBy()` and/or `Any` may force EF to generate an inefficient query

Comment: thanks for your reply can you show me the code to do that?

Comment: i don't wan to use sql query because if using sql euery it's not fit with my project, i prefer using query c# or linq